# Import-on-demand declaration with subpackages only

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javac, jls

Related : [How can I compile "import pack.*" with ant/javac, when there are no such classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878685/how-can-i-compile-import-pack-with-ant-javac-when-there-are-no-such-classes)

Suppose we have the given package structure

```
parent
|
---a
---b
```

where the package `parent` only contains the two subpackges `a` and `b` (no class is under the package `parent`).

The code `import parent.*`, situated in a package other than `parent`, compiled with Maven (i.e. `javac`) throws a compile-time error. The error is:

> package parent does not exist

I looked into the Java Language Specification about such a case (import-on-demand declaration where no types are actually imported). [Paragraph 7.5.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2) about import-on-demand declaration does not seem to specify this behavior.

Is this a bug of `javac`? I am not asking how to circumvent the compile error. I would like to know why `javac` throws an error because I cannot find any reference in the JLS that it should; leading me to believe that this might be a bug.

I tested with JDK 1.4, 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8, the error is the same.

As a side note, there is no compile error with the same code in Eclipse (tested with Eclipse Indigo, Juno, Luna and Mars).

NB: I encountered this behaviour when "mavenizing" an (old) existing project that only relied on the Eclipse compiler. It took me a while to identify that this was the root cause of the compile error I was getting.

Comment: Is it just academic interest or it has any practical value? For me Eclipse behaves stupid by allowing nonsensical statement.

Comment: This is just out of pure interest. I actually never use import-on-demand declaration and prefer single-type-import.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to get Maven to compile these classes? Do you want to know what the JLS is supposed to say? Do you want to know why Eclipse allows it when it shouldn't?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use javac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [section7.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3)

> A package is observable if and only if either:
>
> - A compilation unit containing a declaration of the package is
>     observable (§7.3).
> - A subpackage of the package is observable.
>
> The packages java, java.lang, and java.io are always observable.

And in [7.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2)

> It is a compile-time error if the named package or type is not accessible (§6.6).

So if nothing is in a package it does not exists and the bug is actually on the side of the Eclipse compiler; it's described in a [very old bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18533) that was left in "LATER" state until eventually that state was deprecated and it was moved to WONT_FIX instead. Feel free to re-open it if you think it's worth fixing (now that the JLS is clarified in this area)

Comment: Interesting. However, I added a dummy class to the package `parent.a`, making that subpackage observable, thus making `parent` observable by that rule. And the error is the same.

Comment: Now that sounds like a horrible bug in javac!

Comment: found some more details

Comment: I was mistaken, just retested and the code actually compiles if I add a dummy class to package `parent.a`! I didn't look at this section of the JLS since "observability" of a package isn't mentioned in section 7.5.2. I'll leave the bounty for the moment, just in case there is another answer.

Comment: I think this is the best possible answer, although the deleted one by @chrylis below is also useful in this context. `parent` is not observable until either it or `a` or `b` contain a compilation unit (class, interface, or enum).

Comment: @E-Riz Thanks a lot for this perfect link!