# getting java.lang.NullPointerException even the value is not null

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity

I have Fragment in that I have a method

```
private void update() {
        NetworkingTask task = new NetworkingTask();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String inputValue = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_defualt));
        task.execute(inputValue, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        update();
    }
```

above code works perfect means gets correct result using

```
sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_key),
                    getString(R.string.pref_defualt));
```

pref_general.xml file is

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_defualt"
        android:title="@string/pref_label"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />      

</PreferenceScreen>
```

but in `PreferenceActivity`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

        String prefs_key = getString(R.string.pref_key);

        Log.e("PREFS_KEY_VALE", "Prefs key have " + prefs_key + " as Value");// even here the value is not null

        if (prefs_key != null) {
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(prefs_key));// Here comes NPE
        }    
    }

    public void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference){
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(SettingsActivity.this);

        onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference){
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;

            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0){
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            }
        }else {
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ali.arshad.rhcloud.com.sunshine/ali.arshad.rhcloud.com.sunshine.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at ali.arshad.rhcloud.com.sunshine.SettingsActivity.bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(SettingsActivity.java:30)
                at ali.arshad.rhcloud.com.sunshine.SettingsActivity.onPostCreate(SettingsActivity.java:23)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1939)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can not debug why the NPE comes there!

Comment: I just read the title and not your post: if you are saying you have a NullPointerException on a variable that is not null, do you realize you have just discovered the most astonishing bug the CS world has ever known?

Comment: In other words, it is very likely that your assumptions are at fault, not the JVM. Identify the null variable and then search back in your code to find out why.

Comment: What if `findPreference` returns a null value.

Comment: What show us contents of 'R.xml.pref_general'.

Comment: @Tunaki and I also was when I saw [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004757/import-on-demand-declaration-with-subpackages-only) >:( .

Comment: @Faqeer What do you mean? What is the connection between your post and that question of mine?

Comment: astonishment >:( NTE.

Comment: please change `android:key="@string/pref_defualt"` to `android:key="@string/pref_key"`, because you are binding with key at ` bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(prefs_key));// Here comes NPE`

Comment: @ArshadAli that solved my issue thanks a lot, but why no more answers to this post?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels knows better ask him if?